# Recyclerview takes too long to load when loading large number of images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am trying to load images from a folder in my device to a recyclerview.

I am using Glide to load the images with a preloader for smoother scrolling.

The way which I set the adapter dataset is

I create a `List<String>` of the paths of images and then set it as the adapter's dataset.

My problem is that i takes a long time from the moment I assign the list as the dataset to the moment the `recyclerview` is shown on screen.

Any idea on how to reduce this delay?

Comment: I think main problem is "how many images in the folder"? You can edit your question and specify this problem. Because this is basic problem in your question

Comment: post your code or piece of code till the others can help you

Comment: How about not loading all images at once?

Comment: @engmms Please read [When should code formatting be used for non-code text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561)

Comment: Are you loading images from network or local storage?

Comment: @Zoe thanks for mention

Answer (score 0):

Start loading the images via Glide on onBindViewHolder.